# Test with Jestjs and Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a method that is called on change of the selection component. So this method is public, and what it does is just call two other private methods.

Each method of this private method fills in a variable that is observed by rxjs, so I need to create a test that enters the public method and the two private methods, the first test returning each one a list to fill in the variables, and another that returns an of ([ ]) of catcherror.

In these private methods I use the pipe, because my service already has an error interceptor.

**Here are the variables: :**

```
free$: Observable<ILista[]> | null = null;
grant$: Observable<ILista[]> | null = null;
```

**Here's the general method:**

```
 listagemgeral(event: number) {
    this.disponiveis(event);
    this.concedidas(event);
  }
```

Here is the private method that fills in the free$ variable:

```
private disponiveis(iduser: number) {
    this.free$ = this.service.listarDisponiveis(iduser).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  }
```

**Here is the private method that fills in the variable grant$:**

```
private concedidas(iduser: number) {
    this.grant$ = this.service.listarConcedidos(iduser).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to spy upon the service to check if it was called with the expected parameters.

```
let service = TestBed.Inject(YourService)
const spy1 = jest.spyOn(service, 'listarConcedidos').mockReturnValue(of([]))
component.listagemgeral(7);
expect(spy1 ).toHaveBeenCalledWith(7);
```

Comment: You could also add tests to each variable after that, subscribing to it and using the "done" callback on your tests

Comment: I got this error return